# How to uninstall Internet Explorer 9 or rollback to Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, uninstall, google-earth

I wanted to try, and I installed Internet Explorer 9 and now Firefox is acting strangely. For example, the URL Windows aren't opening in time. When I Maximize Firefox the window title is blinking like crazy.

But [Google Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth) is acting even more strangely. The application seems to work, but when I browse or zoom Earth I immediately experience lots of blinking on my screen.
How do I uninstall Internet Explorer 9 or rollback to Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: Do you have a system restore point from before you installed IE9?

Comment: Yes I have, but since I installed Explorer 9 when I was updating Drivers/Software/Windows Update on a clean  Windows Installation  I don´t want to restore at an earlier point.I would prefer to reinstall Windows from scratch then..

Comment: Isn't IE8 Mode on IE9's Developer Tools enough? (F12, top menu) You can also go back to IE7 and it emulates each browser perfectly.

Comment: @minitech perfectly? I don't know if I can trust that =) I've never had an IE emulator(even MS based) do pixel perfect emulation

Comment: Maybe not pixel-perfect (probably because of the border around the edge) but I promise it won't look any different.

Comment: thanks anyways for the suggestion, but I really have no need for ie9 as I have a very client-driven specification for testing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I updated to IE9 and it also caused problems on my system. Here are the steps I did to roll back to IE8:

1. Open up the Control Panel
2. Click on "Programs and Features" (may be called "Add/Remove programs" if you are using an older version of Windows)
3. Click on "View Installed Updates" in the left pane
4. Right-click on "Windows Internet Explorer 9"
5. Select "Uninstall"
6. Restart your computer when prompted

When it boots back up, it should be running IE8.

Answer (score 4):

Control Panel ---> Uninstall a Program ---> Click View Installed Updates ---> Uninstall the Windows Internet Explorer 9 update.

Any following instructions should be displayed on the screen.

Comment: and that will revert it back to ie8? awesome! I'll check it out

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need to. In IE, if you press <kbd>F12</kbd> (Developer tools) and try different combinations from the two menus (Browser Mode and Document Mode) once the page is loaded, you can test as if IE9 is IE8.

Comment: How does that fix OTHER programs, though?

Answer (score 3):

There should be an entry in Add/Remove programs list to uninstall IE9, which will roll it back to IE8.

Comment: I don see any add/remove program entry for Internet Explorer 9.  Window Operating System is 64bit.

Comment: Did you click "View Installed Updates" on the left side?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to [create a new user profile for Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows), I had this problem unrelated to IE9 and this steps fixed the problem for me. I'm really wondering if rolling back to IE8 will actually fix it for you...

Answer (score 1):

**Vista / Windows 7**

1. Close Internet Explorer
2. Copy the following command to the clipboard:
   `FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*9.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname"`
3. Press the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key or click the Start menu
4. Type `CMD`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or right-click CMD select *Run As Administrator*
6. Right-Click the console window, select paste and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You will have to restart to complete the rollback.
You will also probably need to re-install Adobe Flash Player (this should happen automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I know that in some cases, if you uninstall IE9, it will roll back to IE8. In case that doesn't work, you can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/worldwide-sites.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with Internet Explorer 9 on a 64 bit Windows 7:

1. I opened the *Start* menu and typed in `Windows Features`
2. I unmarked Internet Explorer 9 in the box and then did a restart. I tried to reinstall it, but it would not complete due to the previous version.
3. I found an Internet Explorer update in View and installed the updates. I took that out and then did a restart.
4. I tried another reinstall, but still it did not complete. I checked my [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) 5 browser and took out msn.co.uk from a top site.
5. I installed Internet Explorer 8 on *My Computer*, but it did not like it.
6. I went to Google Chrome search and reinstalled Internet Explorer 9 64 bit. It would not have 32 bit and now all works well.

Whether it was having MSN on Safari 5 Top site as a back up or reinstalling Internet Explorer 8 and then doing the upgrade I don't know. Why is it?